# Google chrome: a ridiculous float bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout

For some reason, if I use line-height property and set it a little smaller, like 13px or so,
the  main text always gets on the bottom div with it's first line.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.main{
                background-color:grey;
                width:500px;
                height:100px;
                text-align:justify;
                line-height:13px;   /* pfff */
            }
            div.pusher{
                float:right;
                height:40px;
            }
            div.bottom{
                float:right;
                clear:right;
                height:60px;
                width:100px;
                background-color:green;
                font-size:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="pusher"></div>
            <div class="bottom">
                    textaaaaa aaaa aaaa
            </div>
            We have yet, many other health products, as they are all beneficiary in some way, aroma therapy products can help you to get more relaxed,
                        relieve the stress and pain, they can help with a better sleep and even protect from mosquitos.
                        Our beverages are also completely natural, and will keep you fresh and in shape!
                        Everyone knows of the coffee benefits, the juices also have vitamins and are highly beneficial.
                        In the beverage section you can also find.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the HTML 4 doctype from 1997?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer for this bug.

The height of the pusher needs to be multiple of line height. Eg. 39px;

In that case it will float text as intended. We can then make the bg transparent and put a litle padding to make it line-up better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a text wrap effect around the green div?

You should float the main text left and have them side by side that will look better then add a clear both dive under them both.

check this too http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

EDIT:

ok you loose the pusher and move the green div outside of main and float it right and use negative margins to put it in to place. And add a clear both dive under main.

or set the main div to position relative and move the green div with absolute positioning

Comment: hmm, I don't think you realize... but I'm trying to make float at the right bottom of the container. and I don't see any other way than using a pusher. if you have a working solution that would do for a google chrome, please be specific and provide one.

Comment: do you realize that absolute position will cancel float?

Comment: Yes I do, and I said Or as in option 2.